# PHP pull from two MySQL tables, where multiple rows in table two

Tags: php, mysql, rows

I have two tables that looks like this:

[image: report table]

[image: picture table]

Put it in images since i dont know how to draw a table here.

My problem is that i can't seem to make a query or anything in my php that will allow me to load the report and the 5 images, so that i can display the images where i want to on the page. As i do it now it loads the report five times and one image in each report.

The edited code after @Terminus suggestions

```
  $sql = "
  SELECT *
  FROM fangstrapporter AS f, rapportbilleder AS r
  WHERE f.id=".htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"])." AND r.id=f.id";

  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo "<b>Overskrift:</b> " . $row["overskrift"] . "<br><br>" . 
    "<b>Sted:</b> " . $row["sted"] . "<br><br>" . 
    "<b>Fangstdato:</b> " . $row["fangstdato"] . "<br><br>" . 
    "<b>Agn:</b> " . $row["agn"] . "<br><br>" . 
    "<b>Kategori:</b> " . $row["kategori"] . "<br><br>" . 
    "<b>Art:</b> " . $row["art"] . "<br><br>" . 
    "<b>Vægt:</b> " . $row["vaegt"] . "<br><br>" . 
    "<b>Længde:</b> " . $row["laengde"] . "<br><br>";

    do {  
      echo "<a href='" . $row["image_path"] . "'><img src='" . $row["image_thumb_path"] . "'></a><br><br>";
    } while($row = $result->fetch_assoc());

    echo $row["beskrivelse"]."<br>";
  } else {
    echo "0 results";
  }
```

Can anyone help me do this? I have been searching on google for four days now, without any success.

Comment: That's basically what you get in 1 query, it's how RDBMS such as MySQL work. It's either this, and extract the report once from the first row, and ignore it while iterating the images, or do 2 queries.

Comment: Why not show the query and the code you're using?

Comment: @Terminus Yeah, that was dumb. Added it now.

Comment: Shouldn't you not use a do-while loop in this situation incase the query doesn't bring back any rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do as @Kenney suggested and remove the part where you echo the report from the loop.

```
$sql = "
  SELECT *
  FROM fangstrapporter AS f, rapportbilleder AS r
  WHERE f.id=".htmlspecialchars($_GET["id"])." AND r.id=f.id";

  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo "<b>Overskrift:</b> " . $row["overskrift"] . "<br><br>" . 
    "<b>Sted:</b> " . $row["sted"] . "<br><br>" . 
    "<b>Fangstdato:</b> " . $row["fangstdato"] . "<br><br>" . 
    "<b>Agn:</b> " . $row["agn"] . "<br><br>" . 
    "<b>Kategori:</b> " . $row["kategori"] . "<br><br>" . 
    "<b>Art:</b> " . $row["art"] . "<br><br>" . 
    "<b>Vægt:</b> " . $row["vaegt"] . "<br><br>" . 
    "<b>Længde:</b> " . $row["laengde"] . "<br><br>";
     $beskrivelse = $row["beskrivelse"];

    do {  
      echo "<a href='" . $row["image_path"] . "'><img src='" . $row["image_thumb_path"] . "'></a><br><br>";
    } while($row = $result->fetch_assoc());

    echo $beskrivelse . "<br>";
  } else {
    echo "0 results";
  }
```

Comment: Thx a lot! That fixed the problem with the images. I know this might be a dumb question, but how do i get "$row["beskrivelse"] to display after the five images? With the code you provided, it displays that row above each image.

Comment: @KennethJ instead of concatenanting it to the end of the first string, use a separate echo statement after the loop.

Comment: i tried that, but for some reason it's not show the "beskrivelse" row when i do it like that.

Comment: @KennethJ I edited my answer when I posted that last comment. Did you try just like the edit?

Comment: Yeah i tried that. It does not echo out "beskrivelse".

Comment: @KennethJ could it be because it's not wrapped by `<b></b>`? can you edit the new code into your question?

Comment: I did that now. I tried the code you suggested in your last edit. I can see that it makes the linebreak, just tried putting in ten of them and it moves the images up. So the linebreak is there, just not the text from the row.

Comment: @KennethJ the error was with my code. Since the loop breaks out only when `$row` is false, there would be nothing g in the "beskrivelse" key at that point. See my edit. Also, you should have seen a warning about `invalid array key` or some such. If not, be sure to turn on [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! That worked like a charm. I will read up on error reporting :) I am rather new at MySQL, so i have a bit of trouble with it. Appreciate the help :)

Comment: @KennethJ you're welcome! And that will only show error regarding PHP (still useful:) It looks like you're usong thw mysqli extension so you might want to take a look at [this for mysql errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)